# sort json object with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to know if there is a true or false reading on a substance from a dataset.

The dataset is something like this (being var drugs for l of 0),

```
{Caffeine: "{"drug":"Caffeine","dose":10,"amount":0}", Ritalin: "{"drug":"Ritalin","dose":"15","amount":1}"}
```

The algorithm i'm using in javascript is something like this currently.

```
  var results = JSON.parse(overall[l].testdetails.result)
    var drugs = overall[l].testdetails.drug
    let substances = false
if (drugs != null) {
  console.log("drugs: ",drugs)

    for (var d = 0; d < drugs.length; d++ ){
      var keyValue=Object.keys(drugs[d])

      console.log("drug: ",drugs.keyValue)
      if(JSON.parse(drugs.d.amount) !=0) {
        substances=true
        break
      }
      // console.log("drugs amount: ",JSON.parse(drugs[d].amount))
    }
  }
```

For some reason I am just unable to do a console log, or parse at all, this dataset.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Your dataset doesn't appear to be an array. I also don't see any attempt to sort anything. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see it would be easier to iterate the drugs list if it was an array. That side, be aware if your data is a string or an object. In your code I got a bit confused about that.

String:

```js
var drugsStr = '{"Caffeine":{"drug":"Caffeine","dose":10,"amount":0}, "Ritalin": {"drug":"Ritalin","dose":"15","amount":1}}';

var drugs = JSON.parse(drugsStr);
console.log(drugs);
```

Object:

```
var drugs = {Caffeine: {drug:"Caffeine",dose:10,"amount":0}, Ritalin: {drug:"Ritalin",dose:"15",amount:1}};
```

So, here is the solution with an object (`drugs`):

```js
var drugs = {Caffeine: {drug:"Caffeine",dose:10,"amount":0}, Ritalin: {drug:"Ritalin",dose:"15",amount:1}};

var keys = Object.keys(drugs);

keys.forEach(key => {
  console.log(drugs[key].drug);
  console.log("drugs amount:", drugs[key].amount);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Json is formatted incorrectly.

```
let drugs = {
    "Caffeine": {
        "drug":"Caffeine",
        "dose":10,
        "amount":0
    },
    "Ritalin" : {
        "drug":"Ritalin",
        "dose":"15",
        "amount":1
    }
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(drugs)) {
  if(value['amount'] > 0 ) {
      console.log( 'Positive for ' + key )
  } else {
    console.log( 'Negative for ' + key )
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the data is in the wrong format, just have to work with what i've got there

Comment: @LeCoda What you've got there isn't valid JSON. Perhaps it's a copy/paste issue? Can double check the JSON you say you're working with?

Comment: @LeCoda like Drew said, your data is not anything anyone can use as it's not valid Json